# IE6 positioning issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, css-position

It works as intended in Safari, Firefox etc. But it is not reading the positioning or z-index in IE6. How can I make it layout as it should in IE6?

Here is the CSS:

```css
.AuthorName_Pic {
    width: 186px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -120px;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 15px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/ThumbDark.jpg) no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Can you put it inside a <pre><code></code></pre> block for formatting's sake please?

Comment: Define: as its should?  We do not know whats wrong or what your trying to do.

Comment: it is laying out how it is supposed to in safari,firefox etc...but is not reading the positioning or z index correctly in IE6

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to address the [box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).  I would use [Tantek's solution](http://tantek.com/CSS/Examples/boxmodelhack.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you are using [Standards Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) not Quirks, otherwise the meaning of ‘width’ and ‘height’ is different in IE to other browsers. This is the box model bug as mentioned by Josh, but you **don't** want to be using a Box Model Hack in this day and age (especially not Tantek's original-and-still-the-worst ugly one). BMHs were needed for IE5 but today are dead and buried, as Standards Mode fixes that issue and a lot more.
2. You say the z-index is wrong in some way. There isn't enough information to say for sure since you have only posted a small part of your code, but a common source of this problem is that IE sets a default ‘z-index’ stacking context on any element you give a ‘position’ (relative/absolute) even when you don't include the z-index attribute. Ensure all the elements you have positioned are also z-indexed to ensure consistent layout cross-browser.